# Pyspark: take based on key in a reducebykey rdd

Tags: pyspark

I have an RDD which is the result of a reduceByKey operation resulting in key-value pairs. I was wondering if there is a way to extract a pair from an RDD based on the key as you would do with a map for instance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are asking a method to get the value by key. If it is what you asking for rdd.lookup(key) would work. 
Can you clarify the question a bit.